# Pass instance variable of Parent to Inner class as parameter of function

Tags: python, python-3.x

At `FactsheetExporter` I have `data` instance variable. I need to pass `data` as instance variable to `Parameter` class but have no ideas how. Do you know how to make it?

```
class FactsheetExporter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {somedata...}

class Parameter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data

    def compute(self):
        do_stuff(self.data)
        # do data stuff...

class PortfolioFactsheetExporter(FactsheetExporter):
    class Meta(FactsheetExporter.Meta):
        name = "export_portfolio_factsheets"
        entities = Parameter()
```

Comment: You use the word "metaclass" in your title, but there are no metaclasses in your code. There is a class named `Meta`.  What is that supposed to do?  The desired relationships between these classes aren't exactly clear.  Could you describe exactly what those relationships should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` here is an instance variable of class `FactsheetExporter`. So, you have to send the instance of `FactsheetExporter` to `Parameter` in order to be able to access `data`.

```
class FactsheetExporter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {somedata...}

class Parameter(FactsheetExporter):
    def compute(self,FactsheetExporter_var):
         data = FactsheetExporter_var.data
         # do data stuff...


object1 = FactsheetExporter()
#Object1 should be passed to Parameter in order for it to be able to access data variable
object2 = Parameter(object1)
object2.compute(value_for_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't kick out PortfolioFactsheetExporter class